# Deleting from a .mdb with input from textbox

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

My delete has the same issue where it says

> *no value given for one or more parameters*

I actually don't know the code to fix this.

This is what I have atm:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      try
      {
          string FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
          sql = " DELETE FROM Club_Member WHERE FirstName = @FirstName; ";
          dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn);

          // Execute query
          dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       catch (System.Exception exc)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
           return;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that obvious?

You declared `@FirstName` parameter in your `SqlCommand` but you never add a value as a parameter.

```
dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn);
dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName);
```

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand`.

```
using(OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
using(OleDbCommand dbCmd = dbConn.CreateCommand())
{
   dbCmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Club_Member WHERE FirstName = @FirstName";
   dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName);
   dbConn.Open();
   dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I always prefer to use [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead of [`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) because `AddWithValue` method sends `nvarchar` type since it is a string variable. But in some cases, you don't want this. You want to declare your [`SqlDbType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as well.

For example, if you have a `varchar` column and you used `AddWithValue` method, ADO.NET send it as an `nvarchar` value and that might cause potential information lost. (for non-Latin characters for example)

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

  try
  {

    string FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;

    sql = " DELETE FROM Club_Member WHERE FirstName = @FirstName; ";
    dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn);

     dbCmd .Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@FirstName",FirstName ));
    // Execute query
    dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (System.Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens mainly because of the Miss spelled values or if you leave any values blank while entering or adding. So database confuses it with a parameter. Debug or just check for spelling. 
BTW I wanted to know what is primary key you are using for Club_Member?

Comment: Misspelling? I don't see any. Main problem seems not adding parameter value.